# IIS 10 hosted website not using CSS file correctly

Tags: css, iis

I've just gotten into creating websites.
I've been trying to host my prototype website using IIS on Windows 10 for the past days now.

Finally I managed to get it up and running using a free DNS provider, No-IP.

Now as I visit the page using Firefox Quantum, it seems like the CSS file is not loading correctly.
(For example even trying without CSS the style="text-align: center;" would not work at all for some reason.)

After trying the same with Google Chrome, it worked correctly.
Trying with Microsoft edge resulted the same as Firefox, leaving the site broken.

I also tried it on mobile. The Android version of both Chrome and the default browser showed a malfunctioning site.

Hence the only correct and working result was Google Chrome on PC.

I also have XAMPP installed, so I tried there as well. Trying that way resulted correctly to my surprise.
(I still hold onto IIS since in case IIS is installed, it uses the default port 80, so XAMPP has to use another one. This way once someone wants to visit the website, they would also need to include the port, (e.g: example.net:8080) which I find quite inconvenient, hence I'm trying my luck using IIS.)

I would like to ask your opinion on this matter. I myself am quite new in the field but am willing to learn more in case anyone had the time to help me out.

Thanks in advance
- Norbert

Comment: Can you provide a sample?

Comment: In the meantime I got some help from a friend's acquaintance. He told me about default files inside each IIS site and how to set them up.
Also how No-IP would be of no use since I've already defined a domain inside IIS and it might cause conflict.

Thanks for the views and replies!